# CentOS 6 and Devtoolset-3

Tags: centos, centos6, devtoolset

Trying to install C++ from [Devtoolset-3](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/) to my CentOS6 system I've ran into dependencies problem:

```
bash-4.2# yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.dhakacom.com
* extras: mirror.dhakacom.com
* updates: centosr4.centos.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-gcc = 4.9.2-6.el6 for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-libstdc++-devel = 4.9.2-6.el6 for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-binutils >= 2.22.52.0.1 for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: devtoolset-3-runtime for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package devtoolset-3-binutils.x86_64 0:2.24-18.el6 will be installed
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.9.2-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) for package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package devtoolset-3-runtime.x86_64 0:3.1-12.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libmpfr.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.el6.x86_64 (rhscl-devtoolset-3-epel-6-x86_64)
        Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

As for me it looks like a bug: SCL should contain updated packages for that libs... but maybe I've missed smth?

Answer (score 0):

`libmpfr.so` is available from [CentOS repository](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.7/x86_64/Packages/mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.i686.html), but it is only 32bit version (I guess that is the case even for other mentioned packages).

There is [bug #1312338](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1312338) filled for this issue. From the comment it looks like issue with CentOS repositories. There is related [bug #1254798](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1254798) about missing ix86 (32bit) builds in the SCL, which might have solve your issue, if you would install this version.

I am afraid I can't help more, then guide you to these bugs, where you can ask for more details. Or you might try to report directly to CentOS if it is related only to CentOS.

As a workaround, you might give a try to [copr repo](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/rhscl/devtoolset-3/) with devtoolset, maybe with the dependencies.

Side question: Do you have enabled related software collections, as noted on the [SCL page](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/), section "Related software collections"?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a reporter of this bug :)

Comment: So it probably didn't help you much so far :) You can try copr repo, related collections or bug directly to CentOS, if you believe it is CentOS related.

Comment: Nope... all of them are not related to C++ (so not interested to me) and I've found they also have no packages containing `libmpfr` or `libgmp` in names.

Comment: checking my RHEL repo installs the `devtoolset-3-gcc-c++` without any problem. It looks like a CentOS repositories issue in some place. But today is see the packages [mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/31367490/dir/centos_6/com/mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) and [gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.x86_64.rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27824130/dir/centos_6/com/gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.x86_64.rpm.html). Could you try to install them manually?